# Moving directly from Point A to Point B

Tags: java, geometry

I got x and y (My position) and also destination.x and destination.y (where I want to get). This is not for homework, just for training.

So what I did already is

```
float x3 = x - destination.x;
float y3 = y - destination.y;

float angle = (float) Math.atan2(y3, x3);
float distance = (float) Math.hypot(x3, y3);
```

I got angle and distance but don't know how to make it move directly.
Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "move directly"?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I mean, that it move from one point to another, but before that it calculates the angle and all how it must go so it goes the shortest path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using this will help

```
float vx = destination.x - x;
float vy = destination.y - y;
for (float t = 0.0; t < 1.0; t+= step) {
  float next_point_x = x + vx*t;
  float next_point_y = y + vy*t;
  System.out.println(next_point_x + ", " + next_point_y);
}
```

Now you have the coordinates of the points on the line. Choose step to small enough according to your need.

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot! It's really awesome! I tweaked the code a little bit to make it simpler and easier to use (for me) :D

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the velocity  from a given angle  use this:

```
velx=(float)Math.cos((angle)*0.0174532925f)*speed;
vely=(float)Math.sin((angle)*0.0174532925f)*speed;
```

*speed=your speed :) (play with the number to see what is the right)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend calculating the x and y components of your movement independently.
using trigonometric operations slows your program down significantly.

a simple solution for your problem would be:

```
float dx = targetX - positionX;
float dy = targetY - positionY;

positionX = positionX + dx;
positionY = positionY + dy;
```

in this code example, you calculate the x and y distance from your position to your target
and you move there in one step.

you can apply a time factor (<1) and do the calculation multiple times, to make it look like your object is moving.

Note that + and - are much faster than `cos()`, `sin()` etc.